# PHP: simple class for storing read-only data structure, array alternative

Tags: object-oriented, php, array, immutability

I need to share some associative data between different parts of my application with two requirements:

- immutability (so read-only)
- safety against mispelling or unavailable index inside the data
- mixed type

I have no need for behaviour, internal state, validation or other DDD related features, just simple read-only data.

For the past I intensively used arrays for such situations but I feel they are more prone to errors due to possible mispelling (trying to access a non existent key would just trigger a notice in standard php configuration) and easy overwriting.

So I recently came to build up a simple class that stores an associative array of data but exposes one and only one way to access it, through php built-in magic methods, throwing exceptions for undefined index inside the data and preventing clients from writing it. Code follows:

```php
class MyData
{

    protected $data;

    public function __construct(array $data) {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function __get($propertyName) {

        if (!array_key_exists($propertyName, $this->data)) {
            throw new Exception("Missing key ".$propertyName);
        }

        return $this->data[$propertyName];
    }

    public function __set($propertyName, $value) {

        throw new Exception("Cannot write ".$propertyName);

    }

}
```

I think this approach would prevent from external writing and trying to access unavailable index, throwing related exceptions and notifying clients in a stronger way than a notice would do.
Indeed this would throw an exception:

```
echo $data->propertyThatDoesNotExist;
```

and also this:

```
$data->propertyThatExists = $newValue;
```

I've already read about arrays vs objects for more or less specific purpose, such as:

- [PHP: when to use arrays, and when to use objects for mostly-data-storing code constructs?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/296752/php-when-to-use-arrays-and-when-to-use-objects-for-mostly-data-storing-code-co)
- [How do I decide whether to make an Input/Output data type an array or a class?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/311688/how-do-i-decide-whether-to-make-an-input-output-data-type-an-array-or-a-class?rq=1)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709578/using-arrays-vs-objects-for-storing-data?noredirect=1&lq=1
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193765/when-should-i-use-stdclass-and-when-should-i-use-an-array-in-php-oo-code

I am curious about what some more experienced developers (even outside of php) think about this solution, thank you very much.

Comment: What are you specifically curious about?  Can you ask a question in which the prima facie answer isn't "I like it" or "I don't like it"?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Is this a convenient approach that fulfills my requirements?

Comment: Only you can answer that.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach does not address spelling issues during development.  Nor do you get any type hinting for your IDE.  There is however a doc annotation that comes in handy:

```
/**
 * @property-read string $name
 * @property-read string $email
 * @property-read string $username
 */
class User
{
    public $name;
    public $email;
    public $username;
```

With this approach your IDE knows exactly which properties your class has and will flag spelling errors.  It will also warn against any attempt to assign a value to a property outside of the class.  Not quite as good as run time read-only protection but it works well for me.  And of course it tells your IDE what the expected types are.

The doc property also works for properties accessed via __get($name).  It basically restricts $name values and again provides type hints.

Just something to consider.

Comment: I did not know about that doc annotation, it's interesting even it's not runtime protection. Thanks!

Comment: Since Cerad is defining public fields for the class instead of magic get/set functions, you get runtime protection as well. `$user = new User(); $user->foo = 4;`  will throw a runtime error when attempting to assign the `foo` property.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I wish it worked that way but php itself has no readonly capability.  Your IDE will complain. phpstorm gives you a nice red flag but the code will actually run just fine.